# one to many matching in matlab

Tags: matlab, matching

I have two folders. I want to find the hierarchicalCentroid of the first image in the folder1 and all the images in the folder 2,then calculate the dist_1_2 between the image in folder1 and each image in the folder2,then find the minimum distance and display it . Again calculate the hierarchicalCentroid of the second image in the folder1 and find the distance with each element in the second folder and calculate the minimum distance and so on.. I write one code,But it want some changes. please help me

```
Dataset='H:\mainproject\codes\letters_numbers';
Testset = 'H:\mainproject\codes\images\test\kk';
plotFlag = 1;
depth = 6;
DataSet      = cell([], 1);
 for i=1:length(dir(fullfile(Dataset,'*.bmp')))
       % Training set process
       k = dir(fullfile(Dataset,'*.bmp'));
       k = {k(~[k.isdir]).name};
       for j=1:length(k)
           tempImage       = imread(horzcat(Dataset,filesep,k{j}));
          imgInfo         = imfinfo(horzcat(Dataset,filesep,k{j}));
         DataSet{j}  = hierarchicalCentroid(tempImage,depth,plotFlag);
          %Feature = feature_extractor(image(j));
         % DataSet{j}   = imresize(hierarchicalCentroid(tempImage),[width height]);
       end
   end
   TestSet =  cell([], 1);
    for i=1:length(dir(fullfile(Testset,'*.bmp')))
       % Training set process
       k = dir(fullfile(Testset,'*.bmp'));
       k = {k(~[k.isdir]).name};
       for j=1:length(k)
          tempImage       = imread(horzcat(Testset,filesep,k{j}));
          imgInfo         = imfinfo(horzcat(Testset,filesep,k{j}));
        TestSet{j}   = hierarchicalCentroid(tempImage,depth,plotFlag);
       end
    end
  dist_1_2 = sum((DataSet{j} - TestSet{j}) .^ 2);
```

Comment: Apologies but what is your actual problem? I understand what you are trying to do but I don't understand what issue(s) you have. Also, please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @kkuilla sorry for the inconvenience.hierarchicalCentroid is a function.Actually I want to match two letters present in different folders by  finding  the minimal distance based on centroid between two letters. First select one letter from the first folder and find the distance between this letter and each letter in the other folder so that i will get a letter that matches with the first letter in the first folder since the distance between this letters are minimum. For this problem i want to make some changes in the code. I get confused in that. because only one value present in the dist_1_2.